# Custom Locust User for SageMaker Endpoint Keeps running after time limit is reached

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, locust

I have been trying to build a SagemakerUser from the base User class in the Locust library. The issue though is when I use it with a timed shape test, when said test ends (you can see a message: Shape test stopping) the load test shrugs it off and continues. Below is the script I have written to this end. My question is how is this behaviour explained?

```
import pandas as pd
from locust import HttpUser, User, task, TaskSet, events, LoadTestShape 
from sagemaker.serializers import JSONSerializer
from sagemaker.session import Session
import sagemaker
import time
import sys
import math
import pdb

df = "some df to load samples from"
endpoint = "sage maker end point name"

class SagemakerClient(sagemaker.predictor.Predictor):
    def predictEx(self, data):
        start_time = time.time()
        start_perf_counter = time.perf_counter()
        name = 'predictEx'
        try:
            result = self.predict(data)
        except:
            total_time = int((time.perf_counter() - start_perf_counter) * 1000)
            events.request_failure.fire(request_type="sagemaker", name=name, response_time=total_time, exception=sys.exc_info(), response_length=0)
        else:
            total_time = int((time.perf_counter() - start_perf_counter) * 1000)
            events.request_success.fire(request_type="sagemaker", name=name, response_time=total_time, response_length=sys.getsizeof(result))
        

class SagemakerLocust(User):
    abstract = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SagemakerLocust, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client = SagemakerClient(
            sagemaker_session = Session(),
            endpoint_name = "sagemaker-test",
            serializer = JSONSerializer())


class APIUser(SagemakerLocust):    
    @task
    def call(self):
        request = df.text.sample(1, weights=df.length).iloc[0]
        self.client.predictEx(request)

class StepLoadShape(LoadTestShape):
    """
    A step load shape
    Keyword arguments:
        step_time -- Time between steps
        step_load -- User increase amount at each step
        spawn_rate -- Users to stop/start per second at every step
        time_limit -- Time limit in seconds
    """

    step_time = 30#3600
    step_load = 1
    spawn_rate = 1
    time_limit =2#3600*6
    #pdb.set_trace()

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()

        if run_time > self.time_limit:
            return None

        current_step = math.floor(run_time / self.step_time) + 1
        return (current_step * self.step_load, self.spawn_rate)
```

Comment: Strange. Can you try to simplify/remove stuff until it works? (or see if it fails regardless of your test plan). How do you launch locust?

Comment: I launch it using `locust -f locustfile.py`. It works and you can see the graph on the dashboard and I can see the requests hitting the api. What I can't understand is why does it ignore the `time_limit` and continue working anyway?

Comment: It also does the same with a headless run.

Comment: Sounds like a real bug. If you can provide a minimal example I can take a deeper look.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to submit this as a bug here and to Locust's github repo as an issue. I will create a working example very soon and provide you with it.